# Need to fetch all strings in a file matching a pattern (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

I have one string say

my $replacedName = UTSXAOU0120JTE01;

And a file name $file = "hosts.txt" containing :

```
1: UTSXAOU0120JTE02 UTSXAOU0120JTE04
2: UTSXAOU0120JTE06 UTSXDOK0120JTE07
3: UTSXAOU0120JDM01 UTSXAOU0120JDM03
```

Following is the code:

```
open(FH, $file) or die ("file not found");
while(my $temp = <FH>)
{
    my @parts = split(/\s+/, $temp);
    if($parts[1])
    {
        if ( $parts[1]=~ grep(/\w{17}TE\d{2}$/, $replacedName))
        {
            print "$parts[1] - FOUND\n" ;
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

I want output as (one by one):

```
UTSXAOU0120JTE04 UTSXAOU0120JTE06 UTSXDOK0120JTE07 UTSXAOU0120JTE04
```

NOTE: "**UTSXAOU0120J**TE**04**
UTSXAOU0120 could be anything and last two nos. could also be anything like 08, 17, 06, etc"

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: Your example is not easily replicable. Is the text file 3 lines or 1 single line? We need to see the desired input (the file) and the desired output from given inputs. Furthermore, the code example is incomplete, it does not compile. At first glance it looks like you're using grep where you should be using a straightforward regex.

Comment: its multiple lines, not in a single line

Comment: Okay, i can see you've correct that. Next your output example needs fixing.it does not match the print. Where is "FOUND" in your output? Furthermore, you only print one match due to the last statment. The output provided is too far off your code for one to guess your intention.

Answer (score 1):

The problem poorly described, based on provided information perhaps OP is looking for something of following kind

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA>; };
my @found = $data =~ /(\w{12}TE\d{2})/g;

say join ' ', sort @found;

__DATA__
1: UTSXAOU0120JTE02 UTSXAOU0120JTE04
2: UTSXAOU0120JTE06 UTSXDOK0120JTE07
3: UTSXAOU0120JDM01 UTSXAOU0120JDM03
```

Output

```
UTSXAOU0120JTE02 UTSXAOU0120JTE04 UTSXAOU0120JTE06 UTSXDOK0120JTE07
```

It is not obvious as from question as from output what role plays `UTSXAOU0120JTE01` if provided output does not match and provided input does not *includes* this string.